# Chrome debugger - parameters in async functions called from template

Tags: google-chrome, typescript, async-await, javascript-debugger

I my template in angular I use following component:

```
 <building-selection 
     (done)="sendToBackend($event)"
     >
 </building-selection>
```

This component show buildings images with checkboxes to user and when he finish checking it emit event with array with chosen buildings

In typescript code below function works:

```
public async sendToBackend(buildings) 
{
    console.log({buildings}); 
    debugger; // I see buildings "debugger variable preview"
    ... 
}
```

But if I comment out `console.log` then in "debugger variable
preview" i see message (if we have non-async function then such phenomenon not appear):

> ReferenceError: buildings is not defined at eval (eval at 
>   (http://project.localhost:3003/main.bundle.js:53596:17),
>   :1:1) at ClientProjectEditorComponent.
>
> ... invokeTask
>   (http://project.localhost:3003/polyfills.bundle.js:14037:14)↵    at
>   HTMLUnknownElement.globalZoneAwareCallback
>   (http://project.localhost:3003/polyfills.bundle.js:14063:17)"
>       **proto**
>       :
>       Error

**Question:** Why `debugger` key word works different when `console` statement is commented out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `async` function will be transformed into a generator function that will iterate each time you `await`. For example:

```
public async sendToBackend(buildings) 
{
    await sleep();
    debugger; 
    await sleep();
}
// Generated js for target es2015

sendToBackend(buildings) {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
        yield sleep();
        debugger; 
        yield sleep();
    });
}
```

As you can see the code of your actual function will end up in an anonymous function that will be passed to the `__awaiter` helper function. The parameter list still exists on the original function, and the anonymous function has acces to the parameters, but if the anonymous function does not capture the parameters by referencing them in it's body then they will not be available for the debugger to inspect. When you add the `console.log` the anonymous function references the parameter and so it will be captured and thus available for inspection in the watch.

The code above was compiled for es2015, the discussion is similar for `es5` but the generated code is more difficult to understand as generators also have to be emulated.